# firebase onAuthStateChanged not triggered after successful login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm fetching a login request to the server(Nodejs) to `signInWithCredential` via token with social auth, or via email, password with basic auth.

I'm using a react-context that will handle the user state with the `onAuthStateChanged` function.

My problem is that the `onAuthStateChanged` function is not triggered after a successful login(when I'll log in with Google/Facebook, for instance, I'll see the new user in firebase auth)

*It'll trigger only after a page refresh(w/o user as it should)

I'll add down here the login route and the user context handler(let me know if you'll need the login client form also which fetch the request to the server):
login route :

```
import { AuthError, 
    EmailAuthCredential, 
    EmailAuthProvider, 
    FacebookAuthProvider, 
    GithubAuthProvider, 
    GoogleAuthProvider, 
    OAuthCredential, 
    signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';
import express from 'express';
import { auth } from '../../src/config/firebaseConfig';

const router = express.Router();

router.post(['/login/email','/login/google','/login/github','/login/facebook'], async (req : express.Request, res : express.Response) => {
    const { token, email, password } = req.body;

    if(!token && !(email || password))
        return res.status(400).json({ message : 'missing fields'});
    
    function getCredential () : OAuthCredential | EmailAuthCredential  {
        switch(req.path)
        {
            case '/login/google' :
                return GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
            case '/login/facebook' :
                return FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
            case '/login/github' : 
                return GithubAuthProvider.credential(token); 
            default : 
                return EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
        }   
    }
    try { return res.status(200).json({ token : await (await signInWithCredential(auth, getCredential())).user.getIdToken() }); }
    catch(err) { return res.status(500).json((err as AuthError).code)}
});


module.exports = router;
```

react-context :

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../config/firebaseConfig'
import { onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth';

const AuthContext = createContext({
    user : null as User|null
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

const AuthProvider : React.FC = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            //not getting triggered to here after successful signInWithCredential
            setUser(user)
            console.log('auth changed');
          });
    }, []);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>{ children }</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
export default AuthProvider;
```

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: Guys I’ll glad to hear your thoughts on it

Comment: Any help would be appropriated

Comment: can someone help me please?

Comment: Where are you calling the `/login/email` route from the front end?